How Can I use TEST_PROTECT in Unity C Test Framework, to achieve a behaviour of the example
I've created the following code snippet to reproduce a problem with my error handling mechanism in Unity C Test Framework.
By using TEST_PROTECT() as it is described in Unity C Test framework documentation I'm unable to achieve the error handling mechanism that I'm doing manually in following example.
But I don't know what I'm missing.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unity.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

void setUp(void) {}
void tearDown(void) {}

static jmp_buf jump_buffer;

void segfault_handler(int signal)
{
    longjmp(jump_buffer, 1); /* should I put UNITY_ABORT() here? */
}

int function_that_crashes(void)
{
    int *val = NULL;
    return *val;
}

void test_function_crash(void)
{
    if (setjmp(jump_buffer) == 0) /* should I put TEST_PROTECT() here? */
    {
        signal(SIGSEGV, segfault_handler);

        TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_INT32(0, function_that_crashes());
    }   
    else
    {
        TEST_FAIL_MESSAGE("[ERROR] Segmentation fault caught\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    UNITY_BEGIN();
    RUN_TEST(test_function_crash);
    return UNITY_END();
}

If I use TEST_PROTECT and TEST_ABORT and examine the code after macro substitution everything seems to be equivalent as the code I've crafted manually. But when I ran the code the behavior is different.

Your code invokes undefined behavior by dereferencing a null pointer. What happens when you remove that?

If I remove the code that introduces UB, the problem is still there because it seems I didn't configure the TEST_PROTECT and TEST_ABORT properly.

I've rewritten the question.

If you've got the answer, please add it as an answer rather than as an addition to the question.  After a few days, you can accept the answer too.  That way, the question appears complete.  Adding the answer as part of the question doesn't give that closure.  See Can I answer myown question?

ok, thanks! I didn't know that.

Unity C Test framework has the macro TEST_PROTECT which call setjmp behind the scenes, but it is not needed in this case because nobody calls longjump.
A solution that seems to works fine, is attach to the signal SIGSEGV a function handler to terminate the test as failed, e.g. TEST_FAIL_MESSAGE("[ERROR] Segmentation fault caught");
The segfault_handler is attached to each test individually by the test fixture setUp function.
In the following example, there are multiple calls to problematic tests, and all test fail without crashing the harness.
#include <signal.h>
#include <unity.h>

void segfault_handler(int signal)
{
    TEST_FAIL_MESSAGE("[ERROR] Segmentation fault caught");
}

void setUp(void)
{
    signal(SIGSEGV, segfault_handler);
}

void tearDown(void) {}

int function_that_crashes(void)
{
    int *val = NULL;
    return *val;
}

void test_function_crash(void)
{
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_INT32(0, function_that_crashes());
}

int main(void)
{
    UNITY_BEGIN();

    RUN_TEST(test_function_crash);
    RUN_TEST(test_function_crash);
    RUN_TEST(test_function_crash);

    return UNITY_END();
}

